# Max and max of two columns or more (date and height)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a system where you can insert the height of kids.
We have a template, which can be edited all the time.
I want a script that selects:
The date of the highest measurement (column 1) and the date newest template (column 2).
The highest measurement is necessarily not registered with the newest template.

I have tried with "Max" and "inner join". Also union, but with no luck.
This is for MSSQL

```
select max(height)
from Kids
union
select max(template)
from Kids
```

So the result could be:

Highest height: 1,63 m.
Newest template: 2019-09-04

Even though the highest height hasn't been measured using the newest template.

Comment: Can you please share your input/expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you are asking. This will return the most recent template and the tallest height.

```
select Tallest = max(height)
    , MostRecent = max(template) 
from Kids
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We have maybe 110 diffent dates of the templates and 2000 measurements. So I just want to select the highest measurement and in the same select statement I want the date of the newste template to be shown. Can you help me if we have hight, weight and BMI schemes and I want these informations for these schemes also?

Comment: You want the date from the row with the highest measurement for each date? Providing some sample data and desired output would make this a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on information you provided, you can try this :

```
 WITH cte AS (
        SELECT height,template,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY template ORDER BY height DESC) rn
        FROM Kids

    )

    SELECT
       *
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn = 1;
```